# Seeking story taking place inside a huge monster with a conjoined brain and heart

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In the late 1980s, I read a short story, probably intended for children or young adults and having several sketched illustrations (in blue ink, I think).  The whole story took place inside a giant space monsters.  The protagonist spent the story traveling around inside the creature, after it ingests his spaceship.  There are occasional short paragraph's from the monster's (stupid) perspective as the hero makes his way toward the thing's heart/brain complex.  There was a final confrontation there before the dual organs.  There was even a picture of the vast fleshy cavern containing them, with the heart many meters high and with arteries wrapped around the similarly sized brain sitting next to the heart.

Any idea what this was?

Comment: Was the protagonist Doctor Who? Did you read it in a Doctor Who Annual? Was the monster named "Voorvolika"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like the Doctor Who short story [The Armageddon Chrysalis](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Armageddon_Chrysalis_(short_story)), published in the [1983 Doctor Who Annual](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Doctor_Who_Annual_1983).

> having several sketched illustrations (in blue ink, I think)

The colour scheme of the illustrations matches your description:

[image]

> The whole story took place inside a giant space monsters. The protagonist spent the story traveling around inside the creature, after it ingests his spaceship.

The TARDIS had either been swallowed by or had materialized within the creature Voorvolika. Voorvolika began to drain life energy from the Doctor, Nyssa, and Tegan.

> There are occasional short paragraph's from the monster's (stupid) perspective as the hero makes his way toward the thing's heart/brain complex.

One such paragraph that I remember was a scene in which the Doctor had wandered into an area of muscle tissue and was in danger of being crushed - he escaped by finding and squeezing a sensitive pressure point, and the creature's thoughts in response to this were "Pain! Voorvolika has never felt pain!". That scene was also illustrated:

[image]

> There was a final confrontation there before the dual organs. There was even a picture of the vast fleshy cavern containing them, with the heart many meters high and with arteries wrapped around the similarly sized brain sitting next to the heart.

And here is the illustration of the final confrontation with the creature's heart/brain:

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's it.  I'm surprised I didn't remember it was Doctor Who.